# How do I speed up slide speed of my owl carousel?

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I'm editing a website that someone else created, it is using an Owl Carousel (Not sure which version) and I have found the part of the code that allows one to customize the carousel. I want to change the duration of time that the slide displays before it changes.

Current Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".homepage-slides").owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        nav: true,
        dots: true,
        autoplay: true,
        loop: true,
        navText: ["<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"],
        mouseDrag: true,
        touchDrag: false,
    });
```

The code does work, if I change the settings they do apply. But when I add `slideSpeed : 8000,` nothing changes, the slides are still too fast.

I have also tried other options such as `autoplaySpeed:8000,` but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Of all you to make you clear please do some research before putting a question to Stack Overflow, It is good to ask questions from seniors but what you have to do is to have some research for your problem. Asking questions of existing solutions can give negative points.

As far as you the solution to your problem try to put following to your code

```
Query(document).ready(function($){
$(".homepage-slides").owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    nav: true,
    dots: true,
    autoplay: true,
    loop: true,
autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:8000 
    navText: ["<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"],
    mouseDrag: true,
    touchDrag: false,
});
```

Comment: Whilst we're on conventions of StackOverflow, if you're going to post fixed code it's helpful if you highlight and explain the changes you've made. Thanks.

Comment: You can search your problem on google that ,There is any existing solution to problem exist ?. If there is a solution already exist people will add negative point to your question which will damage your reputation on stack overflow. Which shows that the author is unclear about his question and shows that he does not have done any research effort  to find a solution.

Comment: Well he's obviously Googled it - where else would he have found 'slideSpeed: 2000' ([this GitHub issue](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/1961))? And he's read either the documentation or the source because he's tried 'autoplaySpeed'. And OK, 'autoplayTimeout' is in [the documentation](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html) too but it's not well described at all ("autoplay interval timeout" isn't obviously better than "autoplay speed") so if that is right I don't think he deserves a lecture - we all miss things and the documentation isn't great.

Comment: dude @Rup sure you are right we all miss things, I think you have got a wrong perception of what I suggested :D

Answer (score 1):

Use `autoplay: 8000` instead of `autoplay: true`, which uses the default timing.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".homepage-slides").owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        nav: true,
        dots: true,
        autoplay: 8000,
        loop: true,
        navText: ["<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"],
        mouseDrag: true,
        touchDrag: false,
    });
});
```

---

Also please check/post your owl version number when this does not work.